# How to find a specific tag in XML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to find a specific tag in XML using javascript, for example: I want to find a tag which name is "`table`" and that tag can be at any place in the XML

XML is:

```
<chater>
    <info>
        <table>
        ........
        </table>
    </info>
    <contetnt>
        <table>
        ........
        </table>
    </contetnt>
</chater>
```

anybody suggest any idea for this

Thanks

Comment: Try using regex or the .test method

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
function loadExample(table)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'data/example.xml',
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) { parseExampleXml(xml, table); }
    });
}

function parseExampleXml(xml, lang)
{
    var $xml = $(xml),
        name = $xml.find('name[table="' + table+ '"]').text(),
}
```

and don't forget to change the names of the function to your function names I just named them Example for the Example.....

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can do this:

```
var $tableTag = $(document).find("table[name='findme']");
```

where "findme" is the value of the "name"-attribute.

```
$tableTag.get(0)
```

will return the acutal HTML-Tag
    $tableTag.length
will return the number of results